# Resizing background image in web page

Tags: html, image-resizing

I have found a relatively big image on the net and i set it as background in my web page. Though it appears in normal size..Is there any simple way to resize it in my html code?
Thank you in advance

Comment: You definatly want to make it smaller on the computer, with a photo editing program like Photoshop, Gimp, or (What I would use on Mac) Preview. If you don't your webpage could take a several seconds to load (which is a long time for the web)...

Answer (score 3):

You can use CSS3 background size property to set the size of the background image. - `http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/WD-css3-background-20020802/#background-size`. But it's better if you resize the image using photo editing s/w and use it as it is advisable to keep the size of a web page as low as possible.

**WARNING**

This is a CSS3 property, and it cant be assured that it'll work perfectly in all the browsers.

**EDIT**

To change the size of the image on the fly according to the browser size using jQuery check this - `http://css-tricks.com/766-how-to-resizeable-background-image/`